# iOS HSP turn off Audio output

Tags: ios, bluetooth, headset, core-bluetooth

I would like to be able to control a bluetooth headset from an iOS device and turn off the audio output, effectively only making it a bluetooth microphone. I am using the HSP headset profile.

Possible?

Pointers?

Comment: To clarify, you are using A2DP and not headset profile HSP?

Comment: did some more reading am using HSP, changed the question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible
BTW where do you want the output to be routed ? on the phone speaker ?

Comment: so you have intimate knowledge of the bluetooth profiles that HSP uses  and sending them commands and you know that this cannot be done? And I know about the current audio routing in AudioSession if that is what you are referring to. I have asked the question of apple about splitting the routing and it cannot be done via AudioSession so I'm wondering if it can by bluetooth comms

Comment: There are no APIs to control the HSP/HFP profiles. Btw, these profiles are always full duplex audio and Bluetooth spec does not provide a way to turn off either one of the half duplex channels.